# Error MSB8020 appeared after uninstalling unused old VS installation

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7-x64

I had Visual studio 2008 installed and working.

I then installed VS 2010 and it worked fine.

I then installed VS Community 2015 and it worked fine.

I then uninstalled VS 2008. I had a hunch that it could cause trouble so I checked that VS Community 2015 still worked - it did.

I then uninstalled VS 2010 and checked that VS Community 2015 still worked - it didn't. When compiling a previously working Community 2015 project I got this:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found.
```

I don't understand why VS 2015 would even be using any parts of VS 2010. Anyway, I'd like to know the most robust way of repairing the situation.

Comment: "Platform Toolset = 'v100'", you uninstalled the toolset that your project requires.  Obvious way to get ahead is to change it to v140.

Comment: Done - perfect. If you put that as an answer instead of a comment then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Surely you now know how to complete the Q+A you started by yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to turn your "comment" into an "answer". I could add an answer myself and mark it as correct but then I'm giving the credit to myself instead of you.

Comment: That's fine, I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installing VS Community 2015 does not by default mean that all the tools used are the latest versions. So when I unisnstalled VS2010 I zapped some of my tools. By selecting "Project" then "retarget solution" I could then update the tools used.

Comment: I couldn't find a "retarget solution" menu item - neither in VS2015 nor in VS2017 (both Community Edition). But the individual projects property pages have a configuration property named "Platform Toolset" (under "General"). This allows to select a toolset, but has to be done for each project in the solution.